# Bind the values of diffrent elements in an array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-binding, binding, bind

Problem:
I want to bind the values in an array in a way that when I change one value the other one will change aswell and vice versa.

```
var array = [1,2,3,1];
array[0] = array[3];
array[0] = 7;
console.log(array[3]) //this will give 1 and I need 7 here.
```

I figured out a way to do this with objects, but it is not as clean as I would like it to be. My friend told me there was no way this could be done but I doubt it.

Comment: And the logic behind getting 7?

Comment: you need to write your own logic for this

Comment: I would assume they're looking for references (array[3] refs array[0]) which you won't find in JS without objects.

Comment: Only objects in javascript can be assigned as reference and you're passing value of `array[3]` which is of type `Number` in your case, and not reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use objects and reference them:

```
var array = [{v: 1}, {v: 2}, {v: 3}, {v: 1}];
array[0] = array[3];
array[0].v = 7;
console.log(array[3].v);
```

To get slightly more readable code, you might wanna implement a custom map:

```
class LinkMap extends Map {
  get(k) {
     return (super.get(k) || {}).value;
  }
  set(k, value) {
     if(super.has(k)) {
       super.get(k).value = value;
     } else {
      super.set(k, { value });
     }
  }
  link(key, to) {
    return super.set(to, super.get(key));
  }
}
```

So one can do:

```
const list = new LinkMap();
 list.set(0, 1).set(1, 2).set(2, 3).link(0, 4);
 list.set(4, 7);
 console.log(list.get(0));
```

Comment: Just to complement: What you are trying to do is not possible with numbers or strings which are accessed by value. So by using an object, you access the reference of the object.